# Find domain of $\log_4(\log_5(\log_3(18x-x^2-77)))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> **Problem**:$\log_4(\log_5(\log_3(18x-x^2-77)))$
> **Solution**:
>
> $\log_3(18x-x^2-77)$ is defined for $(18x-x^2-77) \ge 3$
>
> $(x^2-18x+77) \le -3$
>
> $(x^2-18x+80) < 0$ {As it can't be 0}
>
> $(x-8)(x-10)<0$
>
> $8<x<10$
>
> So domain is $(8,10)$

Am I doing right ??

Comment: $\LaTeX$ tip: "\log_4" produces the nicely rendered $\log_4$.  Without the slash, you only get $log_4$.

Comment: OK,I got it. thanks

Comment: $\log_3(18x-x^2-77)$ is defined for $(18x-x^2-77)>0$ not $\ge 3$

Comment: Yeah,it is clear to me with your ans

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

For for real $m>0$ $\log_ma,$ is defined if $a>0$ as if $\log_ma=b\iff a=m^b>0$

$\log_4(\log_5(\log_3(18x-x^2-77)))$ is defined if $\log_5(\log_3(18x-x^2-77))>0$

$\implies \log_3(18x-x^2-77)>5^0=1$

$\implies (18x-x^2-77)>3^1=3$

$\implies x^2-18x+80<0$

Now, the roots of $x^2-18x+80=0$ are $\frac{18\pm\sqrt{18^2-4\cdot1\cdot 80}}2=8,10$

Now, if $(x-a)(x-b)<0$ where $a,b(<a)$ are real

Either $x-a<0$ and $x-b>0\implies b<x<a$

or  $x-a>0\implies x>a$ and $x-b<0\implies x<b$ which needs $a<x<b$ which is impossible as $a>b$

So, the domain here will be $(8,10)$

Comment: Now first step is more clear to me.thanks a lot

Comment: @rst, nice to hear that. My pleasure

Comment: The last statements can also be expressed as saying that $ \ x^2 - 18x + 80 = ( x - 8 ) \cdot ( x - 10 ) = 0 \ $ identifies the $ \ x-$ intercepts of an "upward-opening" parabola (since the leading coefficient of the quadratic polynomial is positive).  Thus, this polynomial is only greater than zero for  $ \ x > 10 \ $ and $ \ x < 8 \ $ .

Comment: @RecklessReckoner, that's what I've shown algebraically

Comment: I am only commenting on an alternate interpretation of the analysis.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner, thanks. It's always to nice solve a problem in multiple ways. Thanks for your input

Comment: how is  $ x^2-18x+80>0$ possible ??

Comment: @rst, rectified. $18x-x^2-77>3\iff x^2-18x+80<0,$ not $>0$